# Mechanism of the reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

I came across the following reaction,about which I was ignorant till now.Can anyone guide be regarding it with suitable mechanism.[image]

Comment: hello buddy did you try adding the halide resulting in formation of carbocation and the attacking by the oxygen in carboxylic group

Comment: This may enlighten you  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodolactonization

Answer (score 1):

These reaction are called as Lactonization(Generally) these follow a pretty straightforward mechanism the steps are as follow:

1. The $\ce{HCO3-}$ ion from $\ce{NaHCO3}$ Deprotonate the oxygen of carboxylic group to give a negative charge on the oxygen atom
2. Meanwhile the  doublebond forms a non-classical carbocation with $\ce{I2}$
3. The Oxygen atom attacks the non-classical carbocation forming a six membered ring and a $\ce{I}$ on the adjecant atom

This is the mechanism scheme of the above description :
[image]

A similar approach can be followed for the $2^{nd}$ reaction.

Comment: this is not the accepted mechanism for halolactonisation. See the reference given  above

Comment: @Waylander Sir I have corrected it Please reconsider it

Comment: It is worth noting that in the second example the [5] ring is preferred over [6]. This is a general rule of preference for these kind of reactions.

Comment: @Waylander I just noticed it can you please explain why it is so....

Comment: 5-exo-Tet is always favoured over 6-endo-tet by Baldwin's Rules  http://www.reading.ac.uk/acadepts/sd/pharmacy/public_html/staff/andre/BaldwinsRules-RAJ.pdf